# Split xml messages from String

Tags: java, xml, string, arraylist, split

I was wondering if there is a way to split a xml strings.

I have the string here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Replies> <Start>Lets go</Start> </Replies>
```

so I can get each string as array? As this

```
_temp[2] = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>
```

Comment: Split by `[\r\n]+`?

Comment: @BackSlash the xml string already contain "\r\n" after messages tag.

Comment: Then update your question with the proper formatting. If the complete string is as you wrote in the question, splitting by `[\r\n]+` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split using the regex

```
(?<!\A)(?=<\?xml)
```

to split before each `<?xml`.

To prevent the whitespaces at the start of the input to be their own part in the split, you need to `trim` the input however.

Java Example:

```
String input = "   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Messages> <Status>Iam NOT good</Status> </Messages>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Replies> <Start>Lets go</Start> </Replies>";

String[] parts = input.trim().split("(?<!\\A)(?=<\\?xml)");

for (String s : parts) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}
```

**Note:** This will not work for all possible xmls, since `<?xml` can be included in a `CDATA` element, e.g. `<![CDATA[<?xml]]>`. To prevent this, you'd need to use a xml parser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the regex did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another option of reading this can be as follows

```
try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("<XML FILE PATH>"),
                Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(lines.size());
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println("===============================");
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

On running this i got a list of 12 lines that can then be processed using an index.